# Solving second order derivative with Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: integration, heat-equation

I am trying to solve the equation:

$w''(z) = -\frac{q0-qm}{kc*hr}*exp(-\frac{z}{hr})$

with the boundary conditions:

$w'(0) = 0$ and $w'(L) = \frac{qm}{kc}$

I am not sure how to do this where the equation is only defined at the derivative of both boundaries. Is this possible and if so what is the solution?

This is the to solve the inhomogeneous part of a diffusion equation that looks like this:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \kappa \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2} + \frac{\gamma(z)}{\rho c_p}$ for $0\leq z \leq L, t>0$
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}(0,t) = 0 , \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}(L,t) = \frac{qm}{kc}$
$u(z,0) = f(z)$

and I have defined $ u = w(z) + v(z,t)$ where w is the inhomogeneous part and v is the homogeneous part of the equation.

Comment: A whole bunch of this notation should be consolidated.

Comment: Specifically, it looks like this is $w''(z)=Ae^{-Bz}$, so you just integrate twice to get $w=A/B^2 e^{-Bz} + c_1 z + c_2$. But then the BCs tell you $-A/B+c_1=0$ so $c_1=A/B$, and now there either is no solution or else $c_2$ is a free parameter, depending on the other parameters. Physically this compatibility condition amounts to asking whether a steady state exists at all.

Comment: @Ian sorry you're right a lot of the constants should be simplified. Is this the method you would take to solve this PDE or is there a better way to go about this? I have solved this numerically and am attempting to compare my results to the analytic solution.

Comment: As is, no, because you're *probably* trying to shove too much into $w$, to the point that a steady state doing all those other things just doesn't exist. Instead, you can choose either a modified forcing or a modified BC such that $w$ can satisfy that inhomogeneous BVP, and then pass what inhomogeneity is left over onto $v$. You can use the compatibility condition you derived using the method in my second comment to figure out what inhomogeneity you can put onto $w$.

Comment: Thank you very much for you response. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on what I said in the comments here.

Consider $u_t=Au_{xx}+f(x),u_x(t,0)=B,u_x(t,L)=C$. In a steady state solution say $w(t,x)$ with $w_t=0$, you must have

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^L w(t,x) dx = \int_0^L w_t(t,x) dx = 0 = \int_0^L f(x) dx + w_x(L) - w_x(0).$$

If replacing $w_x(0)=B$ and $w_x(L)=C$ results in a true equation, then your solution is just $u=w+v$ where

$$v_t=Av_{xx},v_x(t,0)=0,v_x(t,L)=0.$$

But this probably isn't the case. So instead, you can sacrifice one of the three things that you want to happen. One way is to sacrifice the BC on the right, by taking

$$w_x(0)=B,w_x(L)=B-\int_0^L f(x) dx.$$

Following this route you get

$$v_t=Av_{xx},v_x(t,0)=0,v_x(t,L)=C-B+\int_0^L f(x) dx.$$

Analogously you can sacrifice the BC on the left; I won't write that out.

The other way you can go is to sacrifice the forcing. To do that, choose your favorite $g$ such that $\int_0^L g(x) dx + C - B=0$ and have $w''=g,w'(0)=B,w'(L)=C$, then $v$ will satisfy

$$v_t=A v_{xx} + f(x) - g(x),v_x(t,0)=0,v_x(t,L)=0.$$

I would probably do the last idea with $g(x)=f(x)+\frac{B-C}{L}$, so that $v$ could be evaluated with Fourier series. This way you don't need any differential equation solver, just quadrature.